# Zend Framework and Doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine

I am trying to integrate Doctrine into my Zend Framework application.

In my index, I do following:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()
->registerNamespace('Doctrine')
->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'), 'Doctrine');

 $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
```

as soon as i call doctrine_manager, my zend framework seems to just die after doctrine autoload takes over.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a look at my config and the only difference is:

```
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine','modelsAutoload'));
$manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
```

When you say that you're zend framework dies - are you getting any errors that you can share?

Comment: Sorry for not being to clear. No I do not receive any errors. As soon as I call an instances of doctrine anything below that line of code does not execute. I get no errors either. I tried placing a die underneath but it does not get called. I placed a die in doctrine callloader.php and that gets called.

Comment: I had tried the way you did it also, but doing it that way I get error that cant find Doctrine_manager.

Comment: In full my usual code is

    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()
            ->setFallbackAutoloader(true)
            ->suppressNotFoundWarnings(true);

require_once DOCTRINE_PATH.'/doctrine/Doctrine.php';

and then the above code I've already posted.

Comment: Hey i just tried your way, still same issue. from what i see, when I require doctrine.php thats when it stops.

Comment: Hmm, I might not be understanding the concept. Right now if I do:
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()
 ->registerNamespace('Doctrine')
 ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
& after I declare use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager,
 Doctrine\ORM\Configuration; my website loads up. Do i need to declare the namespaces everytime i want to call doctrine? ex. Models

Comment: Personally I only call it the once, and that's from the Zend bootstrap